# detect URL of the other windows open by a browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, url, dom, browser

I want to know whether it is possible to detect all other windows open and their URL's in a browser using javascript. Cant it be done using DOM.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

This wouldn't be quite secure : it would allow any website to know which other websites a user is visiting at a given instant.

That would be considered as a violation of privacy!

Answer (score 0):

Think about it, wouldnt it be a HUGE security issue? Like, I open my GMail and type my password. While another bad, very bad page has got a javascript code, which does a `document.getElement*` from my GMail tab/window and pushes it to a database or something?

This is something of a very big security issue, also privacy issues are associated with this (as has been pointed out in another answer).

Simple answer for you: NO :-)